# Save video with the exact quality of the source file

Tags: video-quality, codec

I have never had success in saving file with same quality after editing. Either it was much bigger, or quality was worse (square blocks etc). 
I thought MediaInfo program would help, i used to check bitrate of the video, frame rate, codec and make a similar (or close to it) preset in vegas. Never worked.
What i have been using as a solution all these years: save video with high quality, then upload to YouTube and then download from there. 
What are the key characteristics of the source video file i have to check in order to save my editing with the same quality? Maybe there are some good info sources in the internet.

Comment: You need to tell us what codec you are using to save. Sounds like you are using a lossy codec, which, as the name implies, involves some loss of quality

Comment: @stib i usually use H.264. Is it not possible to detect the codec, source video was made with?

Comment: The codec the source video is made with is irrelevant. Once it's opened in the editor it has been decoded to a raster (aka the raw pixels in your video). It then gets re-encoded when you export. Encoding can be lossy for smaller file sizes, or lossless for large file sizes but original quality.